# How to animate removing all children UIViewControllers with one animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uianimation

I would like to remove all children UIViewControllers with one animation. So I wonder if I add removing animation to all children when iterating through them, will it be properly displayed? The effect I would like to achieve is just one animation for this removal.

```
func removeAllChildrenWithAnimation() {
    if let children = viewController?.children {
        for child in children {
            child.willMove(toParent: nil)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                child.view.alpha = 0.0
            }) { (_) in
                child.view.removeFromSuperview()
                child.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this code? What's the actual problem here?

Comment: When turn on slow motion on simulator, I see animations for all children when remove them, but I just want to see only one animation.

Answer (score 0):

You should put everything in one animation block:

I was unable to test this code - I couldn't even type it in Xcode and syntax-check or compile it - so please forgive me if it contains a typo or two. But in general this is how it should work...

```
func removeAllChildrenWithAnimation() {
    guard let children = viewController?.children else { return }

    children.forEach { $0.willMove(toParent: nil) }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        children.forEach { $0.viewIfLoaded?.alpha = 0.0 }
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            children.forEach {
                $0.viewIfLoaded?.removeFromSuperview()
                $0.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    })
}
```